# Cannot install Rstan 2.21 library on CentOS 7 R 4.0.1

Tags: r, rstan

I cannot install the latest version of Rstan using R4.0.1 on CentOS 7 machine.
I followed the instructions found here: https://github.com/stan-dev/rstan/wiki/Installing-RStan-on-Linux

I do not have admin rights to the linux server, so I am wondering if this means I need to ask admin to install V8?
If so, which version - the brew version? (Im not very linux literate).

Any help very much appreciated.

Here is the error:

```
-----------------------------[ ANTICONF ]-------------------------------
Configuration failed to find the libv8 engine library. Try installing:

deb: libv8-dev or libnode-dev (Debian / Ubuntu)
rpm: v8-devel (Fedora, EPEL)
brew: v8 (OSX)
csw: libv8_dev (Solaris)
To use a custom libv8, set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via:
R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars=‘INCLUDE_DIR=… LIB_DIR=…’
---------------------------[ ERROR MESSAGE ]----------------------------
:1:10: fatal error: v8.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘V8’

removing ‘/home/jjannot/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/V8’
ERROR: dependency ‘V8’ is not available for package ‘rstan’
removing ‘/home/jjannot/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/rstan’
The downloaded source packages are in
‘/tmp/RtmpsiiC9D/downloaded_packages’
Warning messages:
1: In install.packages(“rstan”, type = “source”) :
installation of package ‘V8’ had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages(“rstan”, type = “source”) :
installation of package ‘rstan’ had non-zero exit status
```

The details/specs:

Operating System - CentOS 7

RStan Version - 2.21

Output of

```
writeLines(readLines(file.path(Sys.getenv("HOME"), ".R/Makevars")))

CXX14FLAGS=-O3 -march=native -mtune=native -fPIC
CXX14=/usr/bin/g++
CXX14FLAGS=-O3 -march=native -mtune=native -fPIC
CXX14=/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/g++
CXX14FLAGS=-O3 -march=native -mtune=native -fPIC
CXX14=g++
```

Output of

```
devtools::session_info("rstan")─ Session info ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
setting value
version R version 4.0.1 (2020-06-06)
os CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
system x86_64, linux-gnu
ui X11
language (EN)
collate en_US.UTF-8
ctype en_US.UTF-8
tz America/Los_Angeles
date 2020-09-01
─ Packages ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
! package * version date lib source
R rstan [?]

[1] /home/jjannot/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0
[2] /opt/R/64-bit/R-4.0.1/lib64/R/library

R ── Package was removed from disk.
```

Comment: Update: I asked the system admin if they would install V8 and was told to run this linux command `scl enable devtoolset-9 bash`. Still get the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the complete solution in case it can help someone else.

On CentOS 7:

installed V8 headers and shared library from here: https://pkgs.org/download/v8-devel (EPEL_x86_64)

bumped gcc (g++) from version 4 to 9.3.1

In R:

removed rstan and StanHeaders

installed in a fresh R session